# ListView ItemsSource property binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

In my ViewModel I have 2 properties: first is

```
    public ContactList ContactList
    {
        get { return _contacts; }
    }
```

where `ContactList : IEnumerable<Contact>`, and second is just a wrapper

```
public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts
{
    get
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Contact>(ContactList);
    }
}
```

In my view I have an ListView. When I bind this ListView to ContactList - nothing happens, but if I use Contacts property as it's ItemsSource - everything is fine.

Update:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Contacts}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="230">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <views:ContactViewer 
                                DataContext="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ContactToViewModelConverter}}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

As for not working code - I've just changed Contacts to ContactList in binding. And in second case - nothing comes to converter, even no Binding error is displayed.

Comment: What happens if you make your "ContactList" property return an IEnumerable<Contact> instead of a ContactList?

Comment: Have you tried making your binding a one time binding?

Comment: @mydogisbox, what do you mean?

Comment: Mode=OneTime as part of your binding

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you are running into this issue due to the fact that your ContactList is inheriting from IEnumerable instead of ObservableCollection.

Comment: But why? Control's ItemsSource property is type of 'IEnumerable'. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx)

Comment: I don't think that's it - I bind to properties that are plain enumerables all the time.

Comment: Hmm ye I guess that I should review the answer, I checked up on the docs and it seems it's only needing to be an ObservableCollection if you want updates on insert/delete.

Answer (score 0):

I Dont know if Its Your Case .... but Data Should be Available to `ListView` before the ListView is Loaded.... so that It could fill the ListView... if not the You should Use `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that you can tell the ListView that i am loaded.... observable collection fires collection changed notification to listView so listView fills it accordingly... This Should Work

```
     public ContactList ContactList     
     {         
              get 
              { 
                       return _contacts; 
              } 
              Set
              {
                       _contacts= value;
                       OnPropertyChnaged("ContactList");
              }    
     }
```

Plz let me know if it works or not....

Comment: Nope, it isnt this case. I know about all this stuff. In fact `Contacts` property is a wrapper over `ContactList` property and is working.